# Dynamically insert/remove fields using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

In a jsp, I have a plus button and when user clicks it it dynamically generates fields.

Now I want to add a remove link to each field newly added. I have inserted a button and wrote the function. But it does not remove the parent `<tr>` as I expect.

Following is my whole script. Please help if there is another way to remove the row when user clicks the remove button.

Thanks in advance.

my script:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        var iCnt = 1;
        // CREATE A "DIV" ELEMENT AND DESIGN IT USING JQUERY ".css()" CLASS.


        $('#plusbtn').click(function() {
            if (iCnt <= 14) {

                iCnt = iCnt + 1;

                // ADD TEXTBOX.
                $('#headingrow').append('<tr align="left" valign="middle" id="sampleTr" >'+
                        '<td width="12%" valign="bottom" class="content">'+

                        '<select style=" width:165px;" name=attrtype'+iCnt+' ' + 'class="content" id=attrtype'+iCnt+' ' + 'onchange="specialAttr(this);">'+

                        '<option selected="selected" value="">-Data Type-</option>'+
                        '<option value="text">Text</option>'+
                        '<option value="number">Number</option>'+
                        '<option value="currency">Currency</option>'+
                        '<option value="percentage">Percentage</option>'+                                                                                               
                        '<option value="date">Date</option>'+
                        '</select>'+

                        '<input style=" width:165px;" name=attr'+iCnt+' ' + 'id=attr' + iCnt + ' ' + 'type="text" class="content" value="" placeholder="Attribute Name">'+

                        '<input style=" width:95px;" name=attrDec'+iCnt+' '+ 'id=attrDec' + iCnt + ' ' + 'type="hidden" class="content" value="" placeholder="Decimal Points">'+


                        '<input style=" width:90px; background-color: white; color: Red; border: 0px solid;" name="attrRem" id="attrRem" type="button" class="content" value="Remove" >'+   
                    '</td>'+
                '</tr>');


            }
            // AFTER REACHING THE SPECIFIED LIMIT, DISABLE THE "ADD" BUTTON.
            // (20 IS THE LIMIT WE HAVE SET)
            else {      
                $('#plusbtn').hide();
            }

            $('#attrRem').click(function(){
                //window.alert(this.value);
                e.preventDefault();
                $(this).parent("tr").remove();
                iCnt = iCnt-1;
            });

        });





    });

</script>
```

Comment: Provide jsfiddle if possible

Comment: is it going into click event?

Comment: Dhara Parmar Yes I've put an alert and checked. Its going inside and also this element value is fetched correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a function instead of click event or bind a live event. Because your DOM was manipulated everytime you click on Add button.

Try updated code

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
       var iCnt = 1;
       // CREATE A "DIV" ELEMENT AND DESIGN IT USING JQUERY ".css()" CLASS.
       $('#plusbtn').click(function() {
          if (iCnt <= 14) {
            iCnt = iCnt + 1;
            // ADD TEXTBOX.
            $('#headingrow').append('<tr align="left" valign="middle" id="sampleTr" >'+
                    '<td width="12%" valign="bottom" class="content">'+

                    '<select style=" width:165px;" name=attrtype'+iCnt+' ' + 'class="content" id=attrtype'+iCnt+' ' + 'onchange="specialAttr(this);">'+

                    '<option selected="selected" value="">-Data Type-</option>'+
                    '<option value="text">Text</option>'+
                    '<option value="number">Number</option>'+
                    '<option value="currency">Currency</option>'+
                    '<option value="percentage">Percentage</option>'+                                                                                               
                    '<option value="date">Date</option>'+
                    '</select>'+

                    '<input style=" width:165px;" name=attr'+iCnt+' ' + 'id=attr' + iCnt + ' ' + 'type="text" class="content" value="" placeholder="Attribute Name">'+

                    '<input style=" width:95px;" name=attrDec'+iCnt+' '+ 'id=attrDec' + iCnt + ' ' + 'type="hidden" class="content" value="" placeholder="Decimal Points">'+


                    '<input style=" width:90px; background-color: white; color: Red; border: 0px solid;" name="attrRem" id="attrRem" type="button" class="content" value="Remove" click="remove(this);" >'+   
                '</td>'+
            '</tr>');
        }
        // AFTER REACHING THE SPECIFIED LIMIT, DISABLE THE "ADD" BUTTON.
        // (20 IS THE LIMIT WE HAVE SET)
        else {      
            $('#plusbtn').hide();
        }
    });
});
function remove(currObj){
      var $this=$(currObj); 
      $this.parent().remove();
}
</script>
```

Happy coding :)

Comment: Thank you very much it worked. But how can i  reduce the count variable. because i have to allow user to add fields upto 15.

Comment: Don't need to count every time, simply check tr count `var iCnt =$('#headingrow tr').length` you need to put this code inside click event.

Answer (score 1):

`parent()` method of jquery points to immediate parent. Which is in your case is "td" not "tr"

So, to solve this try to use `.closest` method instread of `.parent()`

```
 $('#attrRem').click(function(e){
            //window.alert(this.value);
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).closest("tr").remove();
            iCnt = iCnt-1;
        });
```

Comment: Hardipsinh Thanks for answering. I tried but still not working :(