# Remove last item jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

On click of a button, result appends to another div with the total increasing on each click.

When Remove Last button is clicked it removes the appended div but does not adjust the total.

I've looked all over for a function with no luck.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Remove last</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


  </head>
  <body onLoad="renderTime();">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-4" id="printarea" >
                <div id="print-container">
                    <div class="item"></div>
                    <div class="total"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-8">
                <ul class="final">
                    <li class="remove"><a href="#"><input type="submit" value="Remove Last"  class="print-btn remove-item"></a></li>
                    <li class="remove"><a href="#"><input type="submit" value="Remove All" class="print-btn" data-corners="false" id="submit" onclick="refresh()"></a></li>
                </ul>
                <hr />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <div class="box">
                    <div class="content">
                        <ul class="sub-menu">
                            <li><a href="#"><button class="menu item1">Item 1</button></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><button class="menu item2">Item 2</button></a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        //add item
        $('.item1').click(function(){
           $('<div class="delete">Item 1 - <span class="skill"> 840</span></div><br />').appendTo('.item');

           counter();
        });
        $('.item2').click(function(){
           $('<div class="delete">Item 2 - <span class="skill"> 910</span></div><br />').appendTo('.item');

           counter();
        });

        //remove last item
        $('.remove-item').click(function(){
            $(".delete:last").remove();
        });
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function refresh() {

            setTimeout(function () {
                location.reload()
            }, 100);
        }
    </script>

        <script type="text/javascript">

        var counter = function() {

            var total = 0;

            $(".skill").each(function() {

                total += +$(this).text();
            });

            $('.total').text('Total: ' + total);
        };

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to call `counter();` after `$(".delete:last").remove();`

Comment: Yes, Invoke the `counter();` ... `$('.remove-item').click(function(){
            $(".delete:last").remove();counter();
        });`

Comment: Are you looking something like that [Dynamically insert/remove fields using JQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36935534/dynamically-insert-remove-fields-using-jquery/36935834#36935834)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `counter();` method after the element is removed.

```
//remove last item
$('.remove-item').click(function() {
    $(".delete:last").remove();

    counter();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because you have not called counter function after removing element. you need to call it in remove item clicked handler:

```
 $('.remove-item').click(function(){
        $(".delete:last").remove();
        counter();
 });
```

You should also parse the values while getting the text before calculating total:

```
        var total = 0;

        $(".skill").each(function() {

            total += + parseInt($(this).text() , 10);
        });

        $('.total').text('Total: ' + total);
```